# Can I get server side events sent into Google Tag Manger

Tags: google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol, data-layers

We need to track some server-side events given that some of the activity done by our users is offline over the phone and send these events over to multiple tracking tools and ad networks to stop or intensify remarketing budget.

We have been reading about [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) But this only fixes the issue for GA and other Google products (Google Ads), but it won't fix the issue for other networks (Facebook Ads, AdRoll, Outbrain, etc)

What I think would solve the issue is having these events pushed into Google Tag Manager, and collected by triggers and variables that would shoot out the right tags. This setup would allow our marketing team to stay in control of notifying the desired ad network to take action.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be technically feasible I think making GTM work on server side would be a huge hack. Google Tag Manager is used to manage JavaScript and HTML tags and does not provide any server side API (apart from [REST Api](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2) used to mange your accounts and containers).

The reason why I think it is technically feasible is this: GTM injects scripts to your website and relies on window component and events that do not exist on the server side. Therefore you would have to spin up some client on your server (like Electron) to make it work and then feed events to the client. You can try doing this for fun but I would not advise doing this for any commercial server.

Comment: Thanks Matus, I guess GTM has a new feature request then